# How to automatically inject helper classes in each new module?

Tags: c++, architecture, macros, module, code-generation

Developing a modular application, I want to inject some helper classes into each module. This should happen automated. Note that my helpers have state, so I can't just make them static and include them where needed.

I could store all helpers in a map with a string key and make it available to the abstract base class all modules inherit from.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, void*> helpers;
RendererModule renderer = new RendererModule(helpers); // argument is passed to
                                                       // base class constructor
```

Then inside a module, I could access helpers like this.

```
std::string file = (FileHelper*)helpers["file"]->Read("C:/file.txt");
```

But instead, I would like to access the helpers like this.

```
std::string file = File->Read("C:/file.txt");
```

To do so, at the moment I separately define members for all helpers in the module base class, and set them for each specific module.

```
FileHelper file = new FileHelper(); // some helper instances are passed to
                                    // multiple modules, while others are
                                    // newly created for each one
RendererModule renderer = new RendererModule();
renderer->File = file;
```

Is there a way to automate this, so that I don't have to change to module code when adding a new helper to the application, while remaining with the second syntax? I an not that familiar with C macros, so I don't know if they are capable of that.

Comment: [Somewhat tangential] In your example, do you only have the single instance of `FileHelper` then? If there is only one instance, then why not make it static? Static objects can have state too (static state.) (That's not what I'm suggesting though. I just want to understand the problem.)

Comment: @yzt Sorry, I wasn't specific about that. Such helpers are shared between all modules (to allow exchanging data), while others are created for each module, often with module specific parameters passed to the constructor (to just decouple tasks common in the architecture). I tried to rephrase the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I see what your dilemma is, but I have no good solution for it. However, since there are no other answers, I will contribute my two cents.

I use the combination of a few strategies to help me with these kinds of problems:

1. If the helper instance is truly module-specific, I let the module itself create and manage it inside.
2. If I don't want the module to know about the creation or destruction of the helper(s), or if the lifetime of the helper instance is not tied to the module that is using it, or if I want to share a helper instance among several modules, I create it outside and pass the reference to the entry-point constructor of the module. Passing it to the constructor has the advantage of making the dependency explicit.
3. If the number of the helpers are high (say more than 2-3) I create an encompassing `struct` (or simple `class`) that just contains all the pointers and pass that struct into the constructor of the module or subsystem. For example:

   ```
   struct Platform { // I sometimes call it "Environment", etc.
       FileHelper * file;
       LogHelper * log;
       MemoryHelper * mem;
       StatsHelper * stats;
   };
   ```

   *Note:* this is not a particularly nice or safe solution, but it's no worse than managing disparate pointers and it is straightforward.

All the above assumes that helpers have no dependency on modules (i.e. they are on a lower abstraction of dependency level and know nothing about modules.) If some helpers are closer to modules, that is, if you start to want to inject module-on-module dependencies into each other, the above strategies really break down.

In these cases (which obviously happen a lot) I have found that a centralized `ModuleManager` singleton (probably a global object) is the best. You explicitly register your modules into it, along with *explicit* order of initialization, and it constructs all the modules. The modules can ask this ModuleManager for a reference to other modules by name (kind of like a map of strings to module pointers,) but they do this once and store the pointers internally in any way they want for convenient and fast access.

However, to prevent messy lifetime and order-of-destruction issues, any time a module is constructed or destructed, the ModuleManager notifies all other modules via callbacks, so they have the chance to update their internal pointers to avoid dangling pointers and other problems.

That's it. By the way, you might want to investigate articles and implementations related to the "service locator" pattern.